# Is function literal an expression?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, expression

## Background

> An expression describes a computation and evaluates to a value.

```
> a=2                    // 2 is an expression in assignment statement
> 3                      // is an expression
> [1,2]                  // is an expression
> {'a':2, 'b':[1,2,3]}      // is an expression
> mul(add(4, mul(4, 6)), add(3, 5))   // is an expression
> let result = sum(1,2) // sum(1,2) is an expression in this assignment statement, only because it returns value 3
> console.log(materials.map(material => material.length)); // material => material.length is a sub-expression 
> console.log(materials.map(material => console.log('abc')));   //  material => console.log('abc') is not an expression
> Math.random()                // random() is a method expression
> console.log('xyz')           // log('xyz') is a method expression 
> new Date(2012, 11)           // is an expression
```

In the above examples, `sum(1,2)`, `material => material.length` & `mul(add(4 , mul(4, 6)), add(3, 5))` are call expressions because they follow this evaluation rule:

> Evaluation procedure for call expressions:
>
> 1. Evaluate the operator and then the operand subexpressions
> 2. Apply the function that is the value of the operator subexpression to the arguments that are the values of the operand subexpression

`material => console.log('abc')` does not follow the evaluation rule

[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7329907/3317808) says, The lack of distinction between expressions and commands enables conceptual uniformity (see [Referential transparency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency)) and [bottom-up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bottom-up_parsing) structure.

---

Is function literal(below)

```
   function(){
      console.log('output') 
    }
```

an expression in

```
let f = function(){
      console.log('output') 
    }
```

? Why do we use term [function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function)?

Comment: What you are calling a "function literal", by itself, is a syntax error.

Comment: And, your final example is called a "function expression". So, yes that is an expression because the value of the function is assigned to the variable.

Comment: @ScottMarcus `=` cannot be part of expression

Comment: You are mistaken. Please read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function

Comment: @ScottMarcus MDN defining function expression, does not change the definition of expression. `name = someExpression` is not an expression.

Comment: Well, if you don't want to accept the truth of the language (functions are data in JavaScript), there really isn't any point in you posting your question.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Evaluating an expression should return a value. Function being an object is a different story. Query edited.

Comment: Functions ***are*** values - - that's the point.

Comment: @ScottMarcus function is value from language design point of view. From [expression oriented language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression-oriented_programming_language) aspect, function should evaluate to a value to be eligible as an expression. `sum(1,2)` is not an expression because `sum` function is an object in JS, it is because `sum(1,2)` evaluates to a value

Comment: [sigh] Functions do evaluate to a value!

Comment: Where are you getting these definitions from? JavaScript is not like many other languages and what you are stating as facts are wrong in this context. `console(log)` is absolutely an expression. You are fundamentally not understanding what functions are in JavaScript.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Am getting these rules from [SICP](https://cs61a.org/) course of the discipline we belong to. Hope you are not offended with these rules.

Comment: Exactly! You are taking general CS terms and trying to apply them to a language that doesn't operate in the same way that many languages do.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I do not understand the meaning of this comment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170805/discussion-between-scott-marcus-and-overexchange).

Comment: A function expression is an expression. It evaluates to a function object, which is a value. An assignment (`foo = bar`) is an expression as well (but has sideeffects). It evaluates to the assigned value. `material => console.log('abc')` is an expression too because it evaluates to a function object. You can find all expressions and their evaluation rules in the language spec: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-ecmascript-language-expressions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is anonymous *function expression*, which you assign to variable `f`.
Other examples would be named function expression and IIFE (immediately invoked function expression).

```js
//anonymous function expression
var f = function() {
    return 1;
}
 
//named function expression
var g = function bar() {
    return 1;
}
 
//IIFE
(function helloWorld() {
    alert("Hello world!");
})();
```

In the last example you can see that `function` keyword is wrapped in parenthesis. If there were no parenthesis, it would be considered a statement instead of value and would produce syntax error.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to understand is that in JavaScript, functions wear many hats:

- They are "first-class citizens", that is, **they are data**. They can be stored, they can be passed and they can be assigned.
- They are objects.
- They are invokable units of code.

So, if you accept that the following are expressions:

```
3                      // is an expression
[1,2]                  // is an expression
{'a':2, 'b':[1,2,3]}   // is an expression
```

Then, you can begin to understand how:

```
let foo = function(){}
```

is also an expression - - a function expression. The function *is the value*.

From **[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function)**:

> A function expression is very similar to and has almost the same
>   syntax as a function statement (see function statement for details).
>   The main difference between a function expression and a function
>   statement is the function name, which can be omitted in function
>   expressions to create anonymous functions. A function expression can
>   be used as a IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression) which runs
>   as soon as it is defined. See also the chapter about functions for
>   more information.

And from MDN **[specifically on Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators)**:

> **Expressions**
>
> An expression is any valid unit of code that resolves to a value.
>
> Every syntactically valid expression resolves to some value but
>   conceptually, there are two types of expressions: with side effects
>   (for example: those that assign value to a variable) and those that in
>   some sense evaluate and therefore resolve to a value.
>
> The expression x = 7 is an example of the first type. This expression
>   uses the = operator to assign the value seven to the variable x. The
>   expression itself evaluates to seven.
>
> The code 3 + 4 is an example of the second expression type. This
>   expression uses the + operator to add three and four together without
>   assigning the result, seven, to a variable.
>
> JavaScript has the following expression categories:
>
> - Arithmetic: evaluates to a number, for example 3.14159. (Generally    uses arithmetic operators.)
> - String: evaluates to a character string, for example, "Fred" or    "234". (Generally uses string operators.)
> - Logical: evaluates to true or false. (Often involves logical    operators.)
> - Primary expressions: Basic keywords and general expressions in    JavaScript.
> - Left-hand-side expressions: Left values are the destination of an    assignment.

Since functions ***are*** values, they are expressions, no different than how `3` is an expression because `3` is a value.