# Connection between functional programming and term rewriting

Tags: functional-programming, rewriting

I am interested in the use of term rewriting systems and I found that term rewriting "helps for basic reasoning about functional programs", but I can't understand what it means. I haven't worked with functional programming, but I know the main principles, like pure functions and immutability. Still, I can't get what basic reasoning refers to. Also, is it somehow connected to the inversion of term rewriting?

Comment: it might mean equational reasoning. "*this* is defined as ('is equal to') *that*, so wherever we see *this*, *that* can be used instead" kind of *"basic"* reasoning.

Comment: but why is this only for functional programming? can't we state the same thing about imperative programming for example?

Comment: `x := {print 1; return 1} ; y := x+x`. sets `y` to 2, and prints "1". substitute the `x`'s definition, and it will print "11". so, not the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

They are "connected" because they rely on the same concept: [everything is an expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7327515/everything-is-an-expression):

- In term rewriting, computation is performed by the searching of patterns in expressions, and then the changing of the matched expressions (or subexpressions) to other expressions (rewriting). As a very simple example, the expression `2 + 3` can be transformed into the expression `5` because there is a rewriting rule (that we know as "numerical addition") that knows how to perform such that transformation.
- In functional programming languages, a function is a "first class citizen" of the language, it can be said as "everything is an expression, including a function". So a function can be specified as an argument for function (or procedure) calls, or a function (or a procedure) can return a function ([higher-order functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function)) just like it is done with primitive types.

Additionally, because in in term rewriting "everything is an expression", every one of them must yield a value, just like a function, so a computation by term rewriting can be seen as a successive application of functions.